# How to get link, from hyperlink on telegram messages

Tags: python-3.x, telethon

I'm new with telethon (Python3) and I'm trying to take links from messages.
If there is an hyperlink, this is shown on the console (after a print of the message).

> Processore AMD Ryzen 7 5800X (8C/16T, 36MB di cache, fino a 4,7 GHz max Boost)
>
> [Prrice: € 418.41]
>
> ️ Buy Now! ️ [️ Amazon.it]

Buy Now! is an hiperlink.
Someone can Help Me?

Answer (score 1):

The message object returned by telethon has an entities member which returns a list of entities and all you have to do is iter all the entries and check if they instance matches `MessageEntityTextUrl` then get the url member.

```
from telethon.tl.types import MessageEntityTextUrl
for entity in event.message:
    if isinstance(entity, MessageEntityTextUrl)
        print(entity.url) # your url
```

The above will return the URL, and if you also want the text you need to get `.offset` then either split the `event.text` and get the item at that offset or use any way you find it works for you

Comment: For the offset problem, it's better to use [`Message.get_entities_text`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/latest/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.message.Message.get_entities_text).